# Angular 5, how to refresh sibling components?

Tags: angular, refresh

I'm building my first Angular 5 application with Angular Material table.
After posting a new user with httpClient, I'm simply execute a new GET http call to the server and repopulate the Angular Material table, working great.

But I have a second component showing same data (users), but with slighty different information which also is using Material table to display the data.

My issue is that I don't know how to refresh the second component.
Currently it only updates the second table if I refreshing the page...

I would like to implement same method to the other component, just re-execute a call to the API so the table updates instantly.

Currently the `overview.component.ts` makes the API calls and binds the users in the overview template, using it in the `user.component.ts` with `@Input()`...

**user.overview.component.html**

```
<app-second> [(users)]="users"</app-second>
<app-users> [(users)]="users"</app-users>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnChanges {
   @Input() users: UserDto[];
   displayedColumns = ['name', 'age'];
   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<UserDto>();

   constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog, private _userService: UserService)

   ngOnChanges() {
     this.dataSource.data = this.users;
   }

   loadSites() {
      this._userService.getUsers("../api/customers/")
         .subscribe((users: UserDto[]) => {
         this.users = users
         this.dataSource.data = this.users;
      })
   }

   openCreateUserDialog() {
      let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(AddUserComponent, {
      height: 'auto',
      width: '500px',
      disableClose: true
   })
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   if (result === "cancel") {
      return;
   } else {
      this.loadUsers();
   }
})
}
}
```

**second.component.ts**

```
export class SecondComponent implements OnChanges {
   @Input() users: UserDto[];
   displayedColumns = ['is-approved', 'alias'];
   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<UserDto>(this.users);

   constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog, private _userService: UserService){}

   ngOnChanges() {
      this.dataSource.data = this.users;
   }
```

Basically I only need to know how to update the second component and template/view with an new api call, I don't need some other technique for this task.

Comment: Does the input come from the next parent? how does the parent's array change? because if it is directly, then ngOnChanges hook should be able to catch it, if it's done in a service, then you may want to create an observable

Comment: The both Input()  comes from the parent.
The parent are overview component.

overview makes the API call throw an service.

Comment: Can you show the overview.component.ts?

Comment: swap components , First Call <app-user>, next <app-second> .

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because you are calling API on app-users. This app-users were calling after creating app-second. So that was the reason you are not seeing data in first load.

To achieve this call API on first component or reorder components like below.

```
<app-users> [(users)]="users"</app-users>
<app-second> [(users)]="users"</app-second>
```

Comment: I dont know if were on same page.. I  think I must rewrite my question so it gets more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to initialize an input

move the API call to the parent, and feed the child components with the users as input, like you wanted it to be. `[users]="users"` (no need for the () two-way data binding)

Put this inside overview.component.ts

```
   loadSites() {
      this._userService.getUsers("../api/customers/")
         .subscribe((users: UserDto[]) => {
         this.users = users
         this.dataSource.data = this.users;
      })
```

Comment: I renamed some functions and names in my question because of trying to be more clear, so I forgot to rename loadSite() to loadUsers().

Actually  I already have this function in my overview.component.ts.
I do repeat myself by copying & pasting same GET loadUsers() into user.component, because I wanted a quick way for updating after posting a new post...

Its was easy in the component I was posting to refresh the table, but im stuck refreshing the sibling component.

I'm not sure I can edit my question so I might posting a new with full details, its ony a bit more complex to read/take...

Comment: I would reedit your post and separate it by update. But again, you shouldn't need two-way binding `[()]` for a component input, because data flows in one direction for input.